# different distance depending on input order using fastdtw in python

Tags: python, time-series, dtw

I want to find similarities between time-series and perform Dynamic Time Warping in python using fastdtw (https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw/tree/master/fastdtw).
The computed distance is sometimes changing according to the input order, especially for long time-series.
Here is an example:

```
x = np.random.rand(44)
y = np.random.rand(40)
d1, inx1 = fastdtw(y, x)
d2, inx2= fastdtw(y, x)
d1, d2
```

Any idea why?

Comment: DTW is *not* necessarily symmetric, it is not a true metric, strictly speaking.

Comment: In that case, according to what should the input order (x,y / y,x) be chosen?  I do not have an a priori assumption that one time-series contains the other. Thank you.

Comment: I personally don't know if there's a criterion for that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Why use fastDTW which is approximate and (in spite of its name, slow), when you can compute DTW fast and exact?  https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf